# Remove cache logging with JBoss

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I'm working on JBoss EAP 6.3 and in my server.log file, there is all the time the following logs :

> 10:22:33,525 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]
> (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-70) Pre-invalidating space [users], timestamp:
> 15507410135
>
> 10:22:33,526 DEBUG
> [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]
> (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-70) Invalidating space [users], timestamp:
> 15507409535
>
> 10:22:33,842 DEBUG
> [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]
> (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-50) Pre-invalidating space [users], timestamp:
> 15507410138
>
> 10:22:33,844 DEBUG
> [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]
> (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-50) Invalidating space [users], timestamp:
> 15507409538

How can i remove these logs ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the logging level for hibernate cache is set to `debug`. Setting logging level to `info` means that only log event at info or higher levels are logged.

You can change the logging level with the web console or by using CLI. An example CLI command would look like:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate.cache:add(level=INFO)
```

If you're including Hibernate in your deployment *and* you have a `log4j.properties` consider the following.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
```

or

**log4j.xml file**

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.cache">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.x does not use log4j.